# AFP client for MacOS to connect to AFP server to duplicate and share data with other users

Tags: backup, sharing, nas, afp

I have been in struggle to set a system where I would be able to duplicate and share data with other users.

Under SMB, I had a QSync client being used in MacOS, but seems like it cannot handle extended attributes from each MacOS to the Server. This client is a default one used with QNAP NAS servers.

Using FreeFileSync, I have found several problems trying to run it in real time.

So do you know a good AFP client for MacOS to connect to AFP server to backup and share data with other users, like FreeFileSync?

Comment: I know this isn't an answer (hence why it is in comments) but I have a QNAP NAS and their built-in Time Machine server works a treat, and simple sharing with SMB works fine as well. If you could go into a little more detail on what you are trying to accomplish that would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, but Time Machine is just for backing up and I also want to share with other users, but SMB access cannot handle extended attributes, just with AFP, I have already check this in my QNAS through ssh. I am trying to setup a backup and sharing system in an AIO, like QSync and FreeFileSync does, but saving also extended attributes.